# Wallet-RPC can't connect to remote node

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-rpc

I'm trying to connect wallet-rpc to a remote node but I get an error:

> Wallet initialization failed: no connection to daemon

The remote node is: `node.moneroworld.com:18089`

This is the command that I've run and the output:

```
./monero-wallet-rpc --rpc-bind-port 18082 --wallet-file /path/to/wallet-viewonly --password "" --disable-rpc-login --daemon-host node.moneroworld.com:18089
Monero 'Helium Hydra' (v0.11.1.0-release)
Logging to ./monero-wallet-rpc.log
2018-01-24 09:21:44.048     7f4b347fe740    WARN    wallet.rpc  src/wallet/wallet_rpc_server.cpp:1853   Loading wallet...
2018-01-24 09:21:44.092     7f4b347fe740    WARN    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:2505 Loaded wallet keys file, with public address: address
2018-01-24 09:23:54.631     7f4b347fe740    ERROR   net.http    src/wallet/node_rpc_proxy.cpp:82    Failed to connect to daemon
2018-01-24 09:23:54.632     7f4b347fe740    ERROR   wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1190 result->empty(). THROW EXCEPTION: tools::error::no_connection_to_daemon
2018-01-24 09:23:54.632     7f4b347fe740    WARN    net.http    src/wallet/wallet_errors.h:707  /DISTRIBUTION-BUILD/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1190:N5tools5error23no_connection_to_daemonE: no connection to daemon, request = getversion
2018-01-24 09:23:54.639     7f4b347fe740    ERROR   wallet.rpc  src/wallet/wallet_rpc_server.cpp:1887   Wallet initialization failed: no connection to daemon
```

Does this mean that node.moneroworld.com isn't running? How can I connect to remote node without running daemon on my host?

Update:

I tried with `--daemon-host af.node.moneroworld.com:18089` and the wallet-rpc is connected

```
2018-01-24 09:41:28.701     7f965ac61740    INFO    global  contrib/epee/include/net/http_server_impl_base.h:70 Binding on 127.0.0.1:18082
2018-01-24 09:41:28.712     7f965ac61740    WARN    wallet.rpc  src/wallet/wallet_rpc_server.cpp:1898   Starting wallet rpc server
```

Comment: Try with another node: https://moneroworld.com/#nodes

Comment: If you solved your issue (as your update seems to say), you should post the solution as an answer below so that future readers can use your findings.